# passing json data with { brackets to javascript function displaying error in browser console

Tags: java, json, struts2

(java, struts2, json)
my json strign is below:

```
String chartString= "{'13 ICSC & USF:695.02}~,{'13 Mileage-Kevin Camper LVMS:15.82}~,{'13 WIGC additional expenses:203.15}~,{01-05-14:83.2}";
```

my string is alright

when i pass it to script function

```
onclick="formTablepopup('<s:property value="chartString" escapejavaScript="true"/>')"
```

i'm getting un-terminated error, thats becoz flower braces in string

is there any way to escape {'s in string

Answer (score 0):

escape single quotes and double quotes

Comment: i have added escapejavaScript='true'
the error in browser console is unterimnated strign literal

frametablePopup("image462","img462","{\